# Insert data from one table into two other tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the following:

dbo.vertrag

```
vertrag_id (PK, nvarchar(50), not null)
kunden_id (int, not null)
...
vertrag_von (datetime, not null)
vertrag_bis (datetime, not null)
```

The data from this table should be inserted into two other tables like the following:

dbo.contracts

```
id (PK, int, not null)
contractNumber (nvarchar(50), not null)
...
validityPeriodId (int, not null)
```

dbo.validityPeriods

```
id (PK, int, not null)
validFrom (datetime, not null)
validTil (datetime, not null)
```

Question is about the validity-periods:
So the first task is to create the validity period (vertrag_von, vertrag_bis) in the table 'validityPeriods' and get the identifier back. This identifier-id should then be inserted in the column 'validityPeriodId' while creating the entry in the table 'contracts'.

The query should also check, if the validity-period exists so no duplicate periods should be created.

Additionally this task should run in a job cause the source table might be updated regularly. Maybe it's an idea to truncate the table before each run.

I think this must be possible with a nice query but don't know how to start.

Edit: Some quick example:

dbo.vertrag

```
vertrag_id = 'A33224'
kunden_id = '670'
vertrag_von = '2016-01-02 12:00:00.000'
vertrag_bis = '2016-01-31 12:00:00.000'
```

dbo.contracts

```
id = autgenerated
...
contractNumber = 'A33224'
validityPeriodId = 1
```

dbo.validityPeriods

```
id = 1
validFrom = '2016-01-02 12:00:00.000'
validTil = '2016-01-31 12:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Can you add some sample records and expected output?

Comment: Added some simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's really two queries that can be run as 1 stored procedure; pseudo-code is below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

--insert new periods
INSERT INTO validity_periods (validFrom, validTil)
SELECT DISTINCT a.vertrag_von, a.vertrag_bis
FROM vertrag a
LEFT JOIN validity_periods b ON (a.vertrag_von = b.validFrom) 
AND (a.vertrag_bis = b.ValidTil) 
WHERE b.ID IS NULL

--insert contracts with period_id matching dates
INSERT INTO contracts (contractNumber, validityID)
SELECT a.vertrag_id, b.ID
FROM vertrag a 
JOIN validityperiod b ON (a.vertrag_von = b.validFrom) 
AND (a.vertrag_bis = b.ValidTil) 

COMMIT
```

You may also want to add a UNIQUE index or constraint on the two dates in the valid period table to prevent duplication.